# Store image with mongoengine django

Tags: django, mongoengine

I am working on a project in which I have a Company template which contains a name, url and an image under a Mongoengine Document.
I would like to know how to store the image in the MEDIA folder without having to store it in DB as with the django model that allows direct image upload only in the folder.

Thanks to all

I didn’t find any documentation on the mongoengine website or internet without storing it into db

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It’s not a problem the fact is that I didn’t find any solution to what I’m asking for. I didn’t find anything on the official documentation but maybe someone already had the problem.